# Weigted vest exercises for bodybuilding at home

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, exercise-equipment, crossfit

Since heavy barbells may be [problematic in an appartement](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/16063/3634) I am constantly looking find some alternatives to traditional barbell exercises which I can do at home. This time I want to ask, what possibilities I would gain by using a (heavy) weighted vest and if there are any risks in doing this.

For example one could consider doing squats with a weighted vest (perhaps **and** with dumbbells and possibly also one legged). However a weighted vest provides a characteristic mass distribution, so the forces, especially shearing forces on the spine may be different from using the barbell. Same may be true for the knees.

So, what can I do using a weigted vest (with respect to find alternatives to classical barbell exercises) and how perform the suggested exercises with respect to spine and knee safety compared to the corresponding barbell exercise (done with the same weight for comparison reasons).

Answer (score 1):

I think in answer to your question, it's going come down to what is your starting point?

Are you new to lifting or been lifting for some time?

Have you had any joint weaknesses?

This article seems quite useful:-

http://www.symptomfind.com/healthy-living/weighted-vest-training/

Also, have you considered resistance bands for working out at home?  There's lots of exersises you can do, and they come in different strengths.  Perfect for working out, when space is limited.

There are various websites that stock them but here's one
http://www.elastitone.com/

Another alternative you may consider is TRX
http://www.escapefitness.com/uk/trx-home-kit.html
all you need is a door frame.  Mainly, useful to make body weight exercises more challenging, but TRX, plus weighted vest could give you an awesome workout.

Comment: Links are down.